# How can I change the brightness of the time & date in system tray on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Windows 10 recently updated on my PC and now I can no longer see the time and date icon in the system tray. If I hover over with the mouse it does become a little clearer but you have to squint to see it. If it's a sunny day forget it. I'm so used to just glancing to the bottom right for a quick time check but find it really frustrating now that it's barely visible.

I've gone through settings for date/time and system tray etc but can't find anywhere where this can be adjusted.

Is this one of those annoying things I just have to live with from now on?

Comment: Are you saying that the time and date is not showing at all in the bottom right tray? Or it's there and it just so small? It sounds like your resolution is not set to something useable.

Comment: Version 1607 changed this behavior.  This behavior when it was being tested could be disabled, since its no longer being tested, it cannot be disabled.  There is no way to go back to the old behavior in the current build of Windows 10.  The only way I know, would involve rolling back to Version 1511, then doing a defer upgrade on Version 1607 for 6 months.  At the end of 6 months you would have the same problem though.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Ahackney, the time is still there in the bottom right corner but barely able to see it unless you move cursor over it and then it illuminates a little brighter and briefly flashes up the day and date, as it did before. 

Ramhound, thanks for your response but I'm not tech enough to roll back to a previous version, so will carry on as it is. I've got used to this annoyance now so will live with it. Thanks both for responding.